# Flutter Dio interceptor Error: Bad state: Future already completed

Tags: flutter, dart, interceptor, dio

I have an interceptor to send `jwt token` and to use the `refresh_token` endpoint when the jwt expires.
With an expired jwt I get

```
Error: Bad state: Future already completed
```

error, but the request is processed right anyway. In the console I see one successful response and one with 401 error afterward. How can I solve this issue?

**custom_interceptor.dart**

```
class CustomInterceptor extends DefaultInterceptor {
  ISecureStorage secureStorageService = ISecureStorage();

  @override
  void onRequest(
      RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    LoginModel loginModel = await secureStorageService.readLoginModel();

    options.headers = {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer ${loginModel.access_token}"
    };
    return super.onRequest(options, handler);
  }

  @override
  void onError(err, handler) async {
    if (err.response?.statusCode == 401) {
      final Dio _dio = DioConfig().dio;
      LoginModel loginModel = await secureStorageService.readLoginModel();
      Uri uri = Uri.https(
          "$BASE_URL", "/refresh_token_url");
      try {
        await _dio.postUri(uri, data: {
          "refresh_token": loginModel.refresh_token,
          "grant_type": "refresh_token"
        }).then((value) async {
          if (value?.statusCode == 200) {

            await secureStorageService.deleteLoginModel();
            LoginModel newLoginData = LoginModel.fromJson(value.data);
            await secureStorageService.saveLoginModel(loginModel: newLoginData);
            
            err.requestOptions.headers["Authorization"] =
                "Bearer " + newLoginData.refresh_token;

            final opts = new Options(
                method: err.requestOptions.method,
                headers: err.requestOptions.headers);
            final cloneReq = await _dio.request(err.requestOptions.path,
                options: opts,
                data: err.requestOptions.data,
                queryParameters: err.requestOptions.queryParameters);
            return handler.resolve(cloneReq);
          }
          return err;
        });
        return super.onError(err, handler);
      } catch (e, st) {
        print("ERROR: " + e);
        print("STACK: " + st.toString());
        return super.onError(err, handler);
      }
    } else {
      return super.onError(err, handler);
    }
  }
}
class DefaultInterceptor extends Interceptor {
  @override
  void onRequest(
      RequestOptions options, RequestInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    print(
        'REQUEST[${options.method}] => PATH: ${options.path} | DATA => ${options.data} | JWT => ${options.headers}');
    return super.onRequest(options, handler);
  }

  @override
  void onResponse(Response response, ResponseInterceptorHandler handler) {
    print(
        'RESPONSE[${response.statusCode}] => PATH: ${response.requestOptions.path} | DATA => ${response.data}');
    super.onResponse(response, handler);
    return;
  }

  @override
  void onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
    print(
        'ERROR[${err.response?.statusCode}] => PATH: ${err.requestOptions.path} | SENT_DATA => ${err.requestOptions.data} | RECEIVED_DATA => ${err.response?.data}');
    return super.onError(err, handler);
  }
}
```

**dio_config.dart**

```
class DioConfig {
    static DioConfig _singletonHttp;
    Dio _dio;

    get dio => _dio;

    factory DioConfig() {
        _singletonHttp ??= DioConfig._singleton();
        return _singletonHttp;
    }

    DioConfig._singleton() {
        _dio = Dio();
    }

    dispose() {
        _dio.close();
    }
}
```

**i_secure_storage.dart**

```
abstract class ISecureStorage {

    factory ISecureStorage() => getSecureStorage();

    Future<LoginModel> readLoginModel() async => LoginModel.empty;

    Future<bool> saveLoginModel({LoginModel loginModel}) async => false;

    Future<bool> deleteLoginModel() async => false;
}
```

**web_secure_storage.dart**

```
ISecureStorage getSecureStorage() => WebSecureStorageService();

class WebSecureStorageService implements ISecureStorage {

    final String _loginData = 'loginData';
    html.Storage webStorage = html.window.localStorage;

    @override
    Future<LoginModel> readLoginModel() async {
        return webStorage[_loginData] == null
                ? LoginModel.empty
                : LoginModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(webStorage[_loginData]));
    }

    @override
    Future<bool> saveLoginModel({ LoginModel loginModel}) async {
        webStorage[_loginData] = jsonEncode(loginModel);
        return true;
    }

    @override
    Future<bool> deleteLoginModel() async {
        webStorage.remove(_loginData);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**mobile_secure_storage.dart**

```
ISecureStorage getSecureStorage() => MobileSecureStorageService();

class MobileSecureStorageService implements ISecureStorage {
    final String _loginModel = 'loginModel';

    FlutterSecureStorage storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

    @override
    Future<LoginModel> readLoginModel() async {
        try {
            dynamic _loginData = await storage.read(key: _loginModel);
            return _loginData == null ? LoginModel.empty : LoginModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(_loginData));
        } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
            throw PlatformException(code: ex.code, message: ex.message);
        }
    }

    @override
    Future<bool> saveLoginModel({LoginModel loginModel}) async {
        try {
            await storage.write(key: _loginModel, value: jsonEncode(loginModel));
            return true;
        } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
            throw PlatformException(code: ex.code, message: ex.message);
        }
    }

    @override
    Future<bool> deleteLoginModel() async {
        try {
            await storage.delete(key: _loginModel);
            return true;
        } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
            throw PlatformException(code: ex.code, message: ex.message);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

IN MY CASE the problem was in the first

```
return super.onError(err, handler);
```

It must be `return null;`

So I got it working

Comment: Please share the implementation of secureStorageService

Comment: Also make sure that you are not applying CustomInterceptor when you call refresh_token_url

Comment: Also "refresh_token_url" in the URL looks strange, it is usually "/oauth/token" according to OAuth2, see https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/making-authenticated-requests/refreshing-an-access-token/

Comment: @activout.se i added the custom implementation of secureStorageService. To add: this is a legacy project I'm working on. A lot of thing were working and time is not enough to rewrite everything. refresh_token_url is a custom endpoint on a private webserver, edited to hide actual path, but the problem is I can get the token and make the original request with it, but seems like I have 2 responses ---> the 1st with the data from server; the 2nd with the error

Comment: [HERE a pastebin of the logs](https://pastebin.com/hszR9P6W)

Comment: I found the problem. The call to refresh_token should not return error, but null.
From:

`return err; }); return super.onError(err, handler); } catch (e, st)`

TO

`return err; }); return null; } catch (e, st)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246736/discussion-between-joe-and-activout-se).

Answer (score 6):

You are using `Dio` for the requests. Version `4.0.6` of `Dio` which is the most recent version as of today has this known issue. Please refer to the same on GitHub [here](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/1480).

### Solution

Downgrade your `Dio` package to the last stable version that was known to not have this issue until a new version is released.

In your pubspec.yaml.

```
dio: 4.0.4
```

Then get packages again.

```
> flutter pub get
```

Comment: This issue also happens in 4.0.4

Answer (score 5):

It may be obvious but in my case, after spending couple of days debugging the issue, the cause was calling the handler multiple times.

An `ErrorInterceptorHandler` should be called once, be it `handler.resolve`, `handler.reject`, or `handler.next`. Only one of them should be called **exactly once, not zero times, not more than one,** for each request or the error `Future already completed` will happen.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Solved the issue instead of downgrading to previous versions

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else having this issue and it is not solved by only downgrading dio: Downgrade dio to `4.0.4` AND remove `connectTimeout` from your `BaseOptions`.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 13/02/23:**

- [dio v5.0.0](https://github.com/cfug/dio/releases/tag/v5.0.0) finally contains a fix for this issue.

*Details: At the end flutter-china has transferred the ownership of the dio repo to CFUG and all the changes from the diox hard fork [have been merged](https://github.com/cfug/dio/commit/c3f6fd70936df225e0c628659bf28c4661adf2f1) into the original dio repo, including the fix for this issue.*

---

**Update 15/12/22:**
[`diox`](https://pub.dev/packages/diox) is a hard fork of `dio` made by CFUG group with the aim of [keeping dio well maintained](https://github.com/cfug/diox/issues/29). In `diox`, this issue has already been fixed.

---

*Original answer:*

**Related issue:** https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/1480

There are several open PRs that (try to) tackle this bug:

- https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/pull/1470
- https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/pull/1496
- https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/pull/1550
- https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/pull/1565

If you do not want to downgrade to `dio 4.0.4` as other answers suggest, you can depend on some of these forks until one of them is merged into the official repository.

In my case, I've reviewed and tested [@ipcjs's solution](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/pull/1550) and seems to be working as expected:

```yaml
dio:
  git:
    url: https://github.com/ipcjs/dio
    path: dio/
    ref: b77af132442bf3266ccf11b50ce909711455db3a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class InterceptorsWrapper extends QueuedInterceptorsWrapper {
@override
void onRequest(RequestOptions options,RequestInterceptorHandler handler){
 log('send request：${options.baseUrl}${options.path}');

 final accessToken = Storage.instance.box.read("accessToken");

 options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $accessToken';

 super.onRequest(options, handler);
}

@override
void onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) {
switch (err.type) {
  case DioErrorType.connectTimeout:
  case DioErrorType.sendTimeout:
  case DioErrorType.receiveTimeout:
    throw DeadlineExceededException(err.requestOptions);
  case DioErrorType.response:
    switch (err.response?.statusCode) {
      case 400:
        throw BadRequestException(err.requestOptions);
      case 401:
        throw UnauthorizedException(err.requestOptions);
      case 404:
        throw NotFoundException(err.requestOptions);
      case 409:
        throw ConflictException(err.requestOptions);
      case 500:
        throw InternalServerErrorException(err.requestOptions);
    }
    break;
  case DioErrorType.cancel:
    break;
  case DioErrorType.other:
    throw NoInternetConnectionException(err.requestOptions);
}
super.onError(err, handler);
}
}
...
...
```

This is how I done my Dio Interceptor,
you don't have to return anything in your void onRequest() simply call super.onRequest() and don't use handler instance in interceptor class like

```
return handler.resolve(cloneReq);
```

that part is already done inside onRequest(). I solved my problem in this way
you can also try.

thank you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To instantly solve this problem just comment out the "**connectTimeOut**" field from DioBaseOptions as follows:

connectTimeout: 30000,

Answer (score -2):

*To solve this error, I did like that*

```
void onError(DioError err, ErrorInterceptorHandler handler) async {
  //Halding refresh token other logic
 
//Future.delay solve my error.
  Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5), () => super.onError(err,handler));
}
```